# how do I obtain the ISBN_10 identifier in this complex JSON object

Tags: jquery, json

I am using google book API to display some books.

The API returns an json object with many information, including for each book.

```
"industryIdentifiers": [
   {
    "type": "ISBN_10",
    "identifier": "3640132114"
   },
   {
    "type": "ISBN_13",
    "identifier": "9783640132119"
   }
  ],
```

How can I get the ISBN_10 identifier?

I use the following code to display the information:

```
$.each(data.items, function(i,user){
var tblRow =
"<tr>"
+"<td><img src="+user.volumeInfo.imageLinks.smallThumbnail+"></td>"
..
+"</tr>"
$(tblRow).appendTo("#ergebnisse tbody");
});
```

Comment: What is `data.items`??

Comment: @downvoters: is ignorance a crime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I assume that `user.volumeInfo` (within your `each` loop) is the information about a specific book, then you can find the ISBN_10 value by doing this:

```
var isbn10;
$.each(user.volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers, function(index, entry) {
    if (entry.type === "ISBN_10") {
        isbn10 = entry.identifier;
        return false;
    }
});
```

Basically, `industryIdentifiers` is an array of objects. We can loop through the array using [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/), which will pass us the array index and (more importantly) the entry. We look at each entry's `type` until we find the one that's `ISBN_10`. When we find it, we grab its value and break the `$.each` (by returning `false`). Note that if there is none, `isbn10` will remain `undefined`.

So even if my guess about `user.volumeInfo` is wrong, wherever you get `industryIdentifiers` from, the above will help you find the ISBN_10.